# Not able to extract text from the td tag/element using python scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to extract the text  from the site http://www.jabong.com/Puma-Wirko-Ind-Black-Sneakers-187839.html using x-path:

```
      `item['pcode'] = hxs.select('//*[@id="productInfo"]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]/text()').extract()`
```

I'm getting null value.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following, it works. I used urllib2 to fetch the HTML.

```
text = hxs.select('//div[@id="productInfo"]//table/tr[8]/td[2]/text()').extract()
```

and the following not works:

```
text = hxs.select('//div[@id="productInfo"]//table/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]/text()').extract()
```